# iOS On Demand resources download fine - but they cannot be found in the main bundle by the app at the point I need to use them

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bundle, on-demand-resources

I've gone through the documentation and all the questions on SO related to On Demand assets in iOS and can't find an answer so I'm hoping you can help. I have an app that was able to access files fine (specifically video mp4 files that were in a group/folder with the name "GameVideos"). The code I used to do this is:

```
guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: videoName, withExtension: "mp4") else {
   print("\(videoName) not found")
   return
}

let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
self.player1 = AVPlayer(playerItem: item)
self.videoNode1 = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: self.player1)
```

Now that I've switched to making the video 'On demand' I see the 'not found' message get printed. When it's not listed as an on demand resource, I didn't need to reference the subdirectory - it worked fine without it (though I tried adding it in just to see). I'm also happy that I've not misspelt the file name as that also worked fine.

When creating the On Demand resource - I've set this up with tags and use the following code to call the resources (this code is located in the GameViewController.swift and inside the "viewDidLoad" override - I'm building a SpriteKit game so there is only one view controller - all the other logic is handled in the SKScenes.):

```
let tags = NSSet(array: [
            "OD2",
            "OD3",
            "OD4",
            "OD5",
            "OD6",
            "OD7",
            "OD8",
        ])

  let resourceRequest = NSBundleResourceRequest(tags: tags as! Set<String>)

  resourceRequest.conditionallyBeginAccessingResources(completionHandler: {(resourcesAvailable: Bool) in
            if !resourcesAvailable  { // if resources not available - start download
                resourceRequest.beginAccessingResources(completionHandler: {(err: Error?) in
                    if let error = err {
                        print("Error getting On Demand Resources: \(error)")
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

This code seems to work and I can see the On Demand packages being downloaded successfully in the Disk monitor on Xcode.

Other things I've tried:
I've double checked the target membership of the video and it is correctly assigned.
I've tried calling the Bundle.Main.url with a subdirectory of the folder listed (this didn't work either)
I've tried renaming the folder directory (as it had a space in the name)
I've tried cleaning the build many times

None of the above has worked... what am I doing wrong?? Any guesses or pointers would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after lots of trial and error - I placed the variable 'resourceRequest' in the global scope and it works - the message on the XCode disk changes from "downloaded" to "in use". As you can see in my code, I had previously defined 'resourceRequest' within the GameViewController. I had thought this would work for a SpriteKit game as the GameViewController loads and then it controls all the scenes (so I didn't think it went out of scope).  Someone smarter than me will hopefully say why this works - but for the minute - I'm just happy I can move on and launch my app (Apple's documentation on this stuff is terrible)